# Running main method defined in a test class in Spring Boot 3.2 from Maven?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Spring Boot 3.2 allows starting the application from a main method defined in the test scope. For example:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class TestBootstrap {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    @RestartScope
    fun mongoDbContainer() = MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.2.8")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fromApplication<Bootstrap>().with(TestBootstrap::class).run(*args)
}
```

Normally from command-line Maven, you can start a spring boot application like this:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

But this will run the `main` method defined in the `Bootstrap` class which doesn't start the docker container. I want to run the main method from "test" that loads the `TestBoostrap` configuration. How can I do this from command-line using Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

```bash
$ mvn spring-boot:test-run
```